# Link a PHP file to a database

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans, netbeans-8

I have a few PHP classes (X_Model_TableName format), that represent tables in my MySQL database, with just protected properties, and getters/setters, and I've also added a database connection to NetBeans so it can see what's in my database.

Currently I need to add a column to the database, then open the relevant Model_* file, and add a property, and then generate the getter and setters. I'm wondering if there's a way to sort of link a file to a table, so when I add a column to a table, it will either auto-add the necessary code to the PHP class file.

Does NetBeans have any functionality like this available? I've come across [this](https://code.google.com/p/db2php/) plugin, but it doesn't seem to work, and it's also not exactly what I'm after.

Comment: you need an ORM like [doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).   Although it wouldnt update the getters/setters it would better represent your model as objects which Im kinda getting from your question is what you might want.

Comment: Ahh I didn't think about Doctrine. I think you're right it's what I'm after, but that won't fit in our current MVC without a big rewrite which we unfortunately don't have time for at the moment, definitely something I'll remember for when we do update.

Comment: @nomistic Netbeans is a good IDE which happens to be able to offer a PHP dev environment.

Comment: Yup, look at doctrine or other ORMs and build /migration tools like laravel's artisan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about auto-detecting a new column from the db (you might be able to do that with a macro) but once the protected property is defined, you can autogenerate setters and getters like this:

- Create the new protected property
- Locate your cursor at the point you want the code inserted
- Hit Alt-Insert (or right click and select "Insert Code...")
- Select "Getter and Setter..."
- Click the properties you want to generate getters and setters for
- Click OK
- Profit

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing, which does work well, but who wouldn't want it to be a little quicker if possible :P.

Comment: You could write a macro to do this with a keypress.